# Столбец со словарем переписать в отдельные столбцы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dict

У меня есть столбец:

| all_rel |
| --- |
| `{'Иван': 0.358, 'Михаил':0.25, 'Илья': 0.456}` |
| `{'Иван': 0.698, 'Михаил':0.125, 'Илья': 0.426}` |
| `{'Иван': 0.568, 'Михаил':0.145, 'Илья': 0.464}` |
| `{'Иван': 0.698, 'Михаил':0.125, 'Илья': 0.426}` |

Нужно из него переписать данные в несколько столбцов данным образом:

| all_rel | Иван | Михаил | Илья |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `{'Иван': 0.358, 'Михаил':0.25, 'Илья': 0.456}` | 0.358 | 0.25 | 0.456 |
| `{'Иван': 0.698, 'Михаил':0.125, 'Илья': 0.426}` | 0.698 | 0.125 | 0.426 |
| `{'Иван': 0.568, 'Михаил':0.145, 'Илья': 0.464}` | 0.568 | 0.145 | 0.464 |
| `{'Иван': 0.698, 'Михаил':0.125, 'Илья': 0.426}` | 0.698 | 0.125 | 0.426 |

При этом я не знаю точное значение ключей словаря и их количество, только есть словарь со всеми возможными именами
`name_dict = {'Иван': 0, 'Михаил':0, 'Илья': 0,'Алексей': 0, 'Андрей': 0}`

мой код:

```
for i in range(srt.shape[0]):
    name_dict.update(ast.literal_eval(srt.all_rel[i]))
    srt.rel_dict[i] = name_dict.copy()

    for key in srt.rel_dict[i]:
        srt[key] = ' '

for i in range(srt.shape[0]):
    for key in srt.rel_dict[i]:
        srt[key][i] = srt.rel_dict[i][key]
```

`srt` - имя датафрейма.

Итоговый столбец может содержать и столбцы с другими именами исходного словаря и значением 0 в каждой строке для них.

Есть ли способ это сделать как-то иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На английском SO есть интересный [рецепт](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355928/8324991) под ваш случай:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'all_rel':[
{'Иван': 0.358, 'Михаил':0.25, 'Илья': 0.456},
{'Иван': 0.698, 'Михаил':0.125, 'Илья': 0.426},
{'Иван': 0.568, 'Михаил':0.145, 'Илья': 0.464},
{'Иван': 0.698, 'Михаил':0.125, 'Илья': 0.426},
]})

pd.json_normalize(df['all_rel'])
```

Вывод:

```
    Иван    Михаил  Илья
0   0.358   0.250   0.456
1   0.698   0.125   0.426
2   0.568   0.145   0.464
3   0.698   0.125   0.426
```

В том вопросе по ссылке есть и другие интересные варианты, но этот вроде самый быстрый и простой.

Объединить преобразованные данные с основным датафреймом можно так по индексу:

```
df = df.drop(columns='all_rel') \
       .join(pd.json_normalize(df['all_rel']))
```

Или так, ещё короче, как советует уважаемый MaxU:

```
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('all_rel')))
```

Comment: `df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('all_rel')))` ;)

Comment: @MaxU Да, так совсем красиво, не люблю, когда что-то повторяется, тут название колонки только один раз, красиво )